# Xdebug on Vagrant Scotchbox running PHP 7.2 - Config

Tags: php, vagrant, xdebug, php-7.2

Not a question, but wanted to share with you the config i've used to get xDebug working on Vagrant using Scotchbox with PHP 7.2.

I had issues getting xDebug working with scotchbox and found many pother articles providing suggested configuration but none worked for me.

This was my process:

- vagrant ssh
- sudo pecl install xdebug. if errors read the advice given.
- it says to add ../xdebug.so" to php.ini. copy this line, ie:
  `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so`
- sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
- scroll to bottom > paste:

  `[XDebug]
  sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
  xdebug.remote_enable = 1
  xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
  xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
  xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.33.0
  xdebug.remote_port = 9000
  xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log`
- restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart` or if using https you will need 
  `sudo a2enmod ssl;sudo service apache2 restart`
- in visual studio Code > xDebug config was DEFAULT:

  {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "pathMappings": {
          "/var/www/public/": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "port": 9000,
        "log": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
      }
    ]
  }

I hope this helps somebody as took me hours to work out :)

Comment: If you're trying to do Q&A here, i'd ask the question "How do you get xdebug running on vagrant scotchbox" and post an answer, this format isn't valid.